# How to change a schema key?

Tags: meteor, meteor-autoform

I have a schema defined below and how can I change the predefined schema key (`summary:` key) via meteor template?

```
Schemas.Books = new SimpleSchema(
    {
       summary: {
               type: String
                }
    }
);
```

For instance, I want to change this key through a session variable that was defined by router or through a user input.

Answer (score 0):

Not Sure, Try this

If your schema is like this

```
Books = new SimpleSchema(
    {
       summary: {
               type: String
                }
    }
);
```

then in tempalte helpers,

```
    Books._schema.summary.type = function() { 

      return Session.get("typeValue");
   };
```

In my project I have schema like this

```
RegisterSchema = new SimpleSchema({
    name: {
        type: String
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        regEx: SimpleSchema.RegEx.Email
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        label: "Password",
        min: 8
    },
    confirmPassword: {
        type: String,
        label: "Confirm Password",
        min: 8,
        custom: function () {
            if (this.value !== this.field('password').value) {
                return "passwordMismatch";
            }
        }
    }
});
```

and I'm dynamically setting optional value for email like

```
RegisterSchema._schema.email.optional = function() { return true };
```

this worked for me.

All d best

Answer (score 0):

This is not the thing that I'm trying to do but I have learned a new trick : )

I want to change the schema key that I described above like this.

```
Books = new SimpleSchema(
    {
       bookName: {
               type: String
                }
    }
);
```

Changing `summary:` with `bookName:`

Actually I want to define schema keys dynamically with respect to user information (userId, userName etc.).